# Is this a right behavior?

Tags: c++, exception

```
class foo {
    std::vector<int> datas;
public:
    template <typename It>
    foo(It x, It y) {
        for(; x != y; ++x)
            insert(*x);
    }

    void insert(int val) {
        if(val == 5)
            throw 99;
        else
            datas.push_back(val);
    }

    void print() const {
        for(int x : datas)
            std::cout << x << " ";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7};
    foo* f;
    try {
        f = new foo(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    }catch(int const& x) {
    }
    f->print();
}
```

I suppose that f wouldn't be constructed in this case; the exception thrown by the insert method is not handled in the body of foo constructor. 
I got the following output on gcc 8.2.0 :
1 2 3 5 6 7

Comment: Well, if `new foo` throws and you `catch` then `f->print();` will still try to execute but your pointer is uninitialized. You have undefined behavior.

Comment: "Is this a right behavior?" no this is Undefined Behavior

Comment: Is it?  It is the body of the constructor that is throwing meaning all members have been initialized.

Comment: @NathanOliver If you're asking if it's undefined behavior, if the constructor throws then initialized members are destroyed, construction fails and `new` fails. There is no `foo` to speak of.

Comment: I can't understand the provided manifestation of undefined behavior. `f` should be a random (or null) pointer, and it should not give the reasonable sequence of integers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux oh, right.  Not sure what I was thinking

Comment: @NathanOliver that does not matter - assignment to `f` did not happen, so code pretty match equal to `foo *f; f->print();`

Comment: @Slava exactly right. Where does the sequence come from? Don't say "nasal demons" :)

Comment: @SergeyA One possibility : 1. Since `f->print();` is inevitable you can assume `new foo` never throws (otherwise it's UB). 2. Maybe the compiler can then deduce that `f->print()` is equivalent to `v.print()` since `*f` is essentially a copy of `v`. Edit : Because of the intervening `for` loop is seems like a stretch though.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that's it! f->print means foo never throws, means the check for 5 is redundant and skipped! That's why the sequence has 5 in it.

Answer (score 4):

> I suppose that f wouldn't be constructed in this case;

A `foo` instance would not be constructed in this case.

Furthermore, `f` would not have been assigned to, so its value would remain indeterminate.

> Is this a right behavior?

Accessing an object by indirecting through an indeterminate pointer has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Technically speaking, no. `foo` would not be constructed, the object is constructed only when it's constructor terminates by not throwing an exception.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am afraid for russian reader that really sounds like "No, you are wrong, foo instance would be constructed in this case" :) I also read it this way.

Comment: @Slava I changed the wording to avoid a misunderstanding. I hope it makes sense to Russian speakers now :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, yep, could be language thing. I like it after the edit better - it is clearer, at least to me.

Comment: @Slava: In English it would have to be "No, a `foo` instance would be constructed in this case" with the comma and the "a".

Answer (score 0):

While the undefined nature has been discussed, I feel like it might be interesting to look into actual produced result and speculate why we see it.

While I have no proof, I believe it is an interesting consequence of compiler optimizations and code reasoning. We see that the output is `1 2 3 5 6 7`, even though the code has a `throw` statement for element `5`. How would this happen?

In my view, since we have `f->print()` outside of `try` block, compiler reasons that `f` is never uninitialized - so constructor never throws. Since constructor never throws, `val == 5` is never true! Because of that, the branch is removed. And thus we have the result we do have.

Comment: All the answers so far ignored the output, stressing on undefined behavior. I just tried the code on clang and I got segmentation fault. first time of my life i was happy seeing a seg fault. I mean that's the right behavior to expect in such code. why in gcc the statement f->print() works perfectly as if f is fully constructed and no exceptions is thrown? that's the question.

Comment: @K.Kaland and I hope, I have answered the question?

Comment: You have put forward a hypothesis. How about initialising `f` and adding code before the end of the `try`- and `catch`-block, respectively?

Comment: @SergeyA perhaps you're right but I like to think that gcc has a bug, make my life easier, otherwise I would scan through the c++ standard trying to figure out if gcc did the right thing or not.

Comment: @K.Kaland no, there is no bug in gcc. The bug is in your program. gcc is under no obligation to produce results you expect.

Comment: @SergeyA I know, that's why I said I "like" to think, and not "I think".